# Prove that the set of functions $\{x, e^x, \sin(x)\}$ is linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am supposed to prove that ${x,e^x,\sin(x)}$ is a linearly independent set.

I know that *if* $\{x,e^x,\sin(x)\}$ is linearly independent, *then* we would have $ax+be^x+c\sin(x)=0$, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$, where a=b=c=0.

However, I'm skeptical how to proceed.

My gut tells me to begin taking derivatives, since I'm given a set of real function, and I may be able to to show that $a$, $b$, and $c$ must be equal to zero.

\begin{align*}
(ax+be^x+c\sin(x))'&= a1+be^x+c\cdot cos(x)=0\\
(ax+be^x+c\sin(x))''&=a0+be^x-c\cdot sin(x)=0\\
(ax+be^x+c\sin(x))'''&=a0+be^x-c\cdot cos(x)=0\\
(ax+be^x+c\sin(x))''''&=a0+be^x+c\cdot sin(x)=0\\
\end{align*}
Now subtracting $c\cdot \sin(x)$, we have
\begin{equation*}
be^x=-c(\sin x)
\end{equation*}
From this I can't determine much, I know that $e^x >0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Can someone give me a push?

Comment: What you need to prove is that $$\forall a,b,c\in \mathbb R\left(\forall x\in \mathbb R\left(ax+be^x+c\sin(x)\right)\implies a=b=c=0\right).$$ Take arbitrary real numbers $a,b,c$ and assume that  $\forall x\in \mathbb R\left(ax+be^x+c\sin(x)\right)$ holds. From here you can use a number of tricks, differentiation might help. Personally I'd just replace $x$ with suitable values (start with $x=0$ and see where it gets you, then try to annihilate $\sin$ with something other than $0$).

Comment: Your approach is pretty good. Now notice you have $be^x -c\sin(x) = 0$ and $be^x+c\sin(x)=0$, so adding the two gives $be^x=0$. You can probably take it from there...

Comment: On behalf of @Israel Barquín: I think Cramer method could've done very well with the system formed by your original sum, the second and third derivatives of it.

The determinant of the system with the replaced column will be $0$ in each case.

Answer (score 8):

$ax +be^x +c\sin(x) =0$, $x=0$ implies $b=0$, $ax+c\sin(x) = 0$, $x=\pi$, $a=0$ thus $c=0$

Answer (score 3):

Since $x$, $e^x$, and $\sin x$ are analytic, then their non-vanishing [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian#The_Wronskian_and_linear_independence) is sufficient to conclude that the set is linearly independent.

The Wronskian is equal to the determinant $W$ of the matrix given by

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x & e^x & \sin x\\
1 & e^x & \cos x\\
0 & e^x &  -\sin x\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Therefore, we have

$$W=
\begin{vmatrix}
x & e^x & \sin x\\
1 & e^x & \cos x\\
0 & e^x &  -\sin x\\
\end{vmatrix}
=-xe^x(\sin x+\cos x)+2e^x \sin x$$

Inasmuch as $W\ne 0$ for all $x\in \mathscr{R}$ (e.g., take $x=\pi/2$), then $x$, $e^x$ and $\sin x$ are linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose
$ax +be^x +c\sin(x) =0
$.

If
$b \ne 0$,
then,
for large enough $x$,
$b e^x$
is much larger than
the other two terms,
which is a contradiction.

Therefore
$b = 0$,
so we have
$ax+c\sin(x)
= 0
$.

Again,
if $a \ne 0$,
we can choose $x$
large enough so  that
$|ax| > |c|$.
Since
$|\sin(x)| \le 1$,
this can not hold.

Therefore
$a = 0$,
so that
$c \sin(x) = 0$.

This obviously implies that
$c=0$.

And we are done.